# What could be wrong in this SQL syntax Sqlite3?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Here`s my schema.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Usuarios;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Alunos;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cargo;

CREATE TABLE Cargo (
  Nome_Cargo TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  CargoID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE 
);

CREATE TABLE Usuarios (
  Id_Usuario INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  Nome TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  Cargo TEXT,
  CPF TEXT UNIQUE,
  Is_admin INTEGER,
  User_login TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  Senha TEXT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (CargoID) REFERENCES Cargo(CargoID)
);

CREATE TABLE Alunos (
  Id_Aluno INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  Nome_Completo TEXT NOT NULL,
  RA TEXT UNIQUE,
  Data_Nascimento TEXT,
  RM INTEGER UNIQUE,
  Data_Alteracao NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  FOREIGN KEY (Criado_Por) REFERENCES Usuarios(Id_Usuario)
);
```

I`m receiving the following error:

`sqlite3.OperationalError: unknown column "CargoID" in foreign key definition`

I`m using sqlite3 with Flask in a python application.

I`ve also tried using  https://sqliteonline.com/, but I'm receiving the same error:

`Help: unknown column "CargoID" in foreign key definition`

I've also read through the documentation and some guidelines, but no success.

What could be the syntax error in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a foreign key, you need to define the column *first*.  That is, the foreign key declaration really describes something about an existing column:

```
CREATE TABLE Usuarios (
  Id_Usuario INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  Nome TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  CargoId INTEGER,
  CPF TEXT UNIQUE,
  Is_admin INTEGER,
  User_login TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  Senha TEXT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (CargoID) REFERENCES Cargo(CargoID)
);
```

Note that I replaced `Cargo` with `CargoID`.  Presumably, you can just look up `Cargo` using the foreign key and the `Cargo` table.